# Meteor User table value axtracting

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I pick the email address value from meteor Mongo user table?

I have written below query to pick the element:

```
users=Meteor.users.find({},{emails:1})
```

This the code I have written to fetch the email address, but I don't know how much it's affecting performance in the code:

```
users = Meteor.users.find({})
users.forEach(function(key,option){
    key.emails.forEach(function (key,option){
        console.log(key.address)
    });
});
```

Comment: If you do not know how to proceed from this query I suggest reading some blogs and tutorials about Meteor.

Comment: Also it's not a table but a document store, which has a different structure. You should read about Mongo too.

Answer (score 2):

In meteor, you should call:

```
users = Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: 1 } })
```

[Reference in docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers)

**EDIT**

Please remember `users` is a cursor object. Cursor objects can be handled directly in templates, and must be the return of publications. You can't iterate a cursor directly in a javascript loop.

Example: *(remember authorization in production publications)*

```
Meteor.publish('user-emails', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: 1 } });
});
```

If you want to directly access the user instances, for example to iterate them in a javascript code, you need to `fetch` the cursor ([reference in docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch)).

Example:

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: 1 } }).fetch();
```

Now `users` is an array of users. Feel free to iterate them.

Example (I'm using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)):

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: 1 } }).fetch();
_.each(users, function(user) {
    console.log(user.emails);
});
```

Now, if you need a vector only with emails, one on each index, you can `pluck` the emails from a fetched array with underscore.js ([reference of pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck))

```
var emails = _.pluck(Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: 1 } }).fetch(), 'emails');
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Yea this will return this value  [object Object] from here how i pick the address values ?

Answer (score 1):

if its not working, dont forget to return

```
 return users
```